# how can we add URL with more than one .php variables in .php file itself or maybe in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url

the URL structure of my website is like  merchantview.php?id=$id  where $id echos the merchantname 
at the same time, I want the open the page happening with another .php variable ...suppose merchantfullname.

e.g.
one of my merchantname is Dany while the full name is Dany-Targ

now page loads as follow

/merchantview.php?id=Dany

but at the same time, I want it also to open as

/merchantview.php?id=Dany-Targ

How can it be done?

Comment: You can add whatever http get arguments you want to a URL. That has nothing to do with php, actually. To really answer your vague question you will need to add more context to your question. Where does that `$1` come from? It certainly is not a php variable. So what is the context?

Comment: it's $id which calls the merchantnames I have listed.

Comment: Ah, you changed the content of the question now. Please mark such modifications. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply use multiple http get arguments? For example `/merchantview.php?id=Dany&item=4711`?

Comment: can you help me out with this? i tried but failed. Your code may help me out.

Comment: I gave you code. The question is: _why_ can't you simply do what is suggested and shown in _all_ examples and tutorials? In my last comment I showed how to use _two_ http get arguments. That is what you asked for. Why doesn't that answer your question?